# QT Won't build anything (using VS2015)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, makefile

So I installed QT and I had already installed Visual Studio 2015 and 2017

Here is the error:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\test.exe @C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\test.exe.3864.0.jom
'link' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
jom: C:\Users\pc\Desktop\QT\build-test-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\test.exe] Error 1
jom: C:\Users\pc\Desktop\QT\build-test-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
18:25:04: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.1 MSVC2013 64bit)
The kit Desktop Qt 5.9.1 MSVC2013 64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
```

And here is my environment [kits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjM4v.png) QtVersion 5.9.1 MSVC2013 auto detected and  Manual 5.6.2 [Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obgex.png) debugger and CMake are empty.

I run on a windows 7 enterprise 64bits

Comment: My best guess is that you installed the wrong build environment during your Qt install. You can double check this by running the maintenance tool (Usually found at Windows at C:/Qt/MaintenanceTool.exe), choose the option to 'add or remove components' and you should see a tree of components to install. Expand the 'Qt 5.9.1' section and make sure the options 'msvc2015 64-bit' and / or 'msvc2017 64-bit' are checked. If not, check what you want and click next to apply the changes. Once finished restart Qt creator and you should be able to use those new targets for builds!

Comment: I did that and now i have an error with not finding "cl". I'm trying to reinstall in again